# Does a react component get unmounted and remounted whenever redux store is updated?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

My component has a button. By clicking the button, an action is dispatched and a corresponding API call is made. The response from the API call is stored in redux. But whenever there is an update to the redux store, the component (that I was working on) gets unmounted and remounted. So the component's internal state is destroyed and recreated when the component is remounted.

My question is:

Is it expected for components to unmount and remount whenever the redux store is updated? If it is expected, how should I persist the component's internal state?

AsyncComponent:

```
export default function asyncComponent(importComponent) {
  class AsyncComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    component: null
  };

  isComponentMounted = false;

  componentWillMount() {
    this.isComponentMounted = true;
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const { default: component } = await importComponent();
    if (this.isComponentMounted) {
      this.setState({ component });
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.isComponentMounted = false;
  }

  render() {
    // eslint-disable-next-line react/destructuring-assignment
    const C = this.state.component;

    return C ? <C {...this.props} /> : <Loader />;
  }
}

return AsyncComponent;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It totally depends on your implementation and not on Redux state.

If you have a condition to render the component then when the condition is false the component may get destroyed. If you're passing state as a prop then it may just update without unmounting.

In your case it seems like you're using state as a condition to render the component.

Comment: I am not using condition to render the component. But I am using HOC to render component asynchronously. This component gets unmounted and remounted whenever redux store is updated. I have updated the post with HOC code.

Comment: Your `asyncComponent` is fine. Check the logic where you're rendering the returned component which you're saying is re-mounting.

Answer (score 0):

On redux store update the component will not re-mount, it will re-render.It may happen that the parent component is getting re-render and your current component is getting data through props from parent, hence you are observing the issue.Please check the parent component once.